# Continue to show video from camera when app is in background for iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, avcapturesession, zoom-sdk

I have been working on a video calling application, for my usecase, I would like to show the video of a person in the call even though he has backgrounded my application.

In apple doc, it is specified that it can be achieved from iOS 16 using `isMultitaskingCameraAccessEnabled` by checking `isMultitaskingCameraAccessSupported` in AVCaptureSession object

Here is my code that I used but im unable to show video and in info.plist manifest screen, multiple window is enabled.

How do I show it like how zoom and whatsapp does.

```
class AVCaptureSessionHelper {
  
  let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
  
  func startCapturingSession() {
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
      if captureSession.isMultitaskingCameraAccessSupported {
        captureSession.isMultitaskingCameraAccessEnabled = true
      }
    }
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }
  }
  
  func stopCapturing() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    }
  }
}
```

But its not working. can someone help with this?